# Python job submission to spark from remotely

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python script with pyspark code on my local system. I am trying to submit a pyspark job from my local machine to remote spark cluster.

Please let me know how it can be done.
Do I need spark locally installed to submit spark job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the spark master URL in the spark conf like below

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CDX JSON Merge Job").master("spark://ip-address:7077")
                .getOrCreate();
```

You have to install the spark client in your localhost and then execute the jar using the `spark-submit`

```
spark-submit --num-executors 50 --executor-memory 4G --executor-cores 4 --master spark://ip-address:7077 --deploy-mode client --class fully-qualified-class-name  artifact.jar
```

You can also have the master as YARN if you are running Spark on YARN and deploy-mode as cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I am running spark on Yarn mode. Do we need to specify spark master url or I need to copy some hadoop conf file and set some env variables.